# How to get the title of the Webform?

Tags: drupal-6, webforms, block

I have a webform.
I have written the php code in my module file which executes on webform submission.
In the code, I want to get the title of webform, and the name of the file attached to the webform.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your .module file and write a select query in your function. Look at the code below.

```
function get_node_title($nid){
```

$node = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = %d", $nid));
  return $node->title;
}

Comment: Well but I want to do this without the query.